# SVN Keywords File doesn't update after switch revision

Tags: eclipse, svn, keyword

Hi I am using svn in Eclipse.

My problem is that the File with the keywords doesn't update when I switch the revision. Example I am on the trunk, my file show me that

```
// File name: $HeadURL: svn://svnsrv.blabla.de/TestProjekt/trunk/TestProjekt/SVNInfo.txt $
// Revision: $Revision: 30 $
// Last modified: $Date: 2019-06-04 09:04:08 +0200 (Di, 04 Jun 2019) $
// Last modified by: $Author: scn $
```

and when i create now a tag und switch to him, it shows me the same file but if i look in TortoiseSVN the file is updated.

Is there an option in Eclipse to activate this? Is my way the right?

My file `SVNInfo.txt` is in the project directory.

```
// File name: $HeadURL$
// Revision: $Revision$
// Last modified: $Date$
// Last modified by: $Author$
```

Then I set `svn:keywords` with `Set Property...` on the Projekt and then set keywords.

[image: svn set keywords]
At last i commit the Project.

Comment: update your WC after switch it to tags

Comment: nothing change after update the WC. If i load the project new like New -> SVN -> Project from SVN, then is the file updated.